# How to create a half circle expandable menu in android java

Tags: android

I need to build a menu in android that starts as a half circle and once tapped, exposes menu options drawn in an arc around the half circle.

I have experimented with canvas drawing and while it achieves the desired result, there isn't a way to add touch events easily and allow me to animate the menu as i would like.

Is there a library or a better way that will allow me to achieve this.

The background needs to have an overlay and the menu positioned above the overlay to simulate general menu opening as it works on web.

Screenshot of current menu screen:
[image: Menu Screenhshot]

I need to be able to add touch events to each individual menu item and allow it to open close as well as bring it to the front of the text as even though i have drawn the menu last, the text stays above.

I'm using drawArc, drawCircle and drawText to do it all.

Anything better I can use?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a Radial Menu. You can use this widget to get what you are looking for - [Radial-Menu-Widget-Android](https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android).

Comment: Thank you Virus. I appreciate your help!